# How to convert numbers among hex, oct, decimal and binary in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

What is the general way to convert numbers among hex, oct and binary in OCaml?

For example, how to convert hex 4294967276 (FFFFFFFC) to decimal number?

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 11):

It's not clear what you're asking. Numbers are just numbers, really. They don't have a base (ignoring the hardware representation). The time you have a base is when you convert numbers to and from strings. To interpret a string as a decimal integer you can use `int_of_string`. For other bases, you can use `Scanf.sscanf`. To convert a number to a decimal string you can use `string_of_int`. For other bases, you can use `Printf.sprintf`.

```
# int_of_string "345";;
- : int = 345
# Scanf.sscanf "FC" "%x" (fun x -> x);;
- : int = 252
# string_of_int 345;;
- : string = "345"
# Printf.sprintf "%X" 252;;
- : string = "FC"
#
```

Granted, `Scanf.sscanf` is fairly cumbersome to use. But I don't know of any other conversion functions in the OCaml Standard Library.

**Update**

As observed by barti_ddu, if you don't mind adding a prefix to your input string you can use `int_of_string` for all 4 of the bases you mention:

```
# int_of_string "0xFC";;
- : int = 252
# int_of_string "0o374";;
- : int = 252
# int_of_string "0b11111100";;
- : int = 252
```

(Or maybe your input already has the prefix, in which case this is a *much* simpler solution.)

Comment: btw, int_of_string accepts other bases too, e.g. `int_of_string "0xF"`

Comment: This is a good point, thanks. If you don't mind messing with your string of digits a little bit you can use int_of_string for all 3 bases. Maybe I should update my answer....?

Comment: Yes, sure; it may also be useful to mention that hexes/octals may be used directly in the code by prefixing with their base (e.g. `let x = 0xF in let y = 0o10 ...`. Sorry for spamming, i'm too distracted today :)